# about Branch cut of square root

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, solution-verification

Let $\log (z)$ denote the branch of the logarithm with imaginary part lying in $(-\pi, \pi]$, and define $\sqrt{z}= \exp(\log(z)/2)= \sqrt{r}\exp(i \theta/2)$ for $z=re^{-i\theta}$, where $-\pi < \theta \le \pi$, and $\sqrt{r}$ denotes the positive square root of $r$.

a) For which complex numbers $z$ does $\sqrt{z^2}=z$ hold?

b) Explain which step in the following is false, and why:

$1=\sqrt{1}=\sqrt{(-1)(-1)}= \sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1} = i^2=-1$

a) We have either $\sqrt{z^2}= z$ or $-z$.

$\sqrt{z^2}= \sqrt{r^2} \exp{(2i\theta/2)}= r \exp{(2i\theta/2)}$.

If $\sqrt{z^2}=-z= e^{i\pi}re^{i\theta}= re^{i\pi+i\theta}$, then $re^{i\pi+i\theta}= r \exp{(2i\theta/2)}$ , which is not right.

b) The third equality is false, because by above we have $\sqrt{(-1)^2}=1$.

Could someone please check my answer? I'm not super sure if my reasoning is correct for a). If not, how would you approach this question?

Thanks!

Comment: You didn't answer the question for a).  $\sqrt{z^2}\ne z$ when $|\arg(z)|>\frac\pi2$..  And for b}, you need to provide a reason (example when it fails) why $\sqrt{(-1)(-1)}\ne \sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: how did you get $|\arg(z)|> \frac{\pi}{2}$ for part a?

Comment: Let say $z=e^{i3\pi/4}$, so that $\arg(z)=3\pi/4>\pi/2$.  Note $z^2=-i$ so that $\arg(z^2)=-\pi/2$.  Clearly $\sqrt{z^2}=e^{-i\pi/4}=- z=-e^{i3\pi/4}$